# How to order a dictionary based on the keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that the keys representing the item and the value represent count of that.
for example in below dictionary:

```
dict= {'11': 4, '0': 2, '65': 1, '88': 1, '12': 1, '13': 1}

'11' occurred 4 times
'0' occurred 2 times
'65' occurred 1 time
```

How to order the dictionary that dict.keys() are descending or ascending?

The Ideal out put will be either

```
dict={'0':2,'11':4,'12':1,'13':1,'65':1,'88':1}
```

or

```
dict={'88':1,'65':1,'13':1,'12':1,'11':4,'0':2}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you remember to [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) before posting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: Also, please don't use `dict` as a variable name, its a builtin already.

Comment: There is a special case version of dict called [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Might that be useful here? Also do you want the dict to be actually ordered or are you only looking to iterate it in ascending or descending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to older posts dictionaries are no longer unordered and can be sorted since CPython 3.6 (unofficially, as a C implementation detail) and Python 3.7 (officially).

To sort by key use a dictionary comprehension to build a new dictionary in the order desired.  If you want to sort by string collation order, use the following, but note that `'2'` comes after `'11'` as a string:

```py
>>> d = {'11': 4, '2': 2, '65': 1, '88': 1, '12': 1, '13': 1}
>>> {k:d[k] for k in sorted(d)}
{'11': 4, '12': 1, '13': 1, '2': 2, '65': 1, '88': 1}
```

To order by integer value, pass a key function that converts the string to an integer:

```py
>>> {k:d[k] for k in sorted(d,key=lambda x: int(x))}
{'2': 2, '11': 4, '12': 1, '13': 1, '65': 1, '88': 1}
```

Or reversed you can use `reverse=True` or just negate the integer:

```py
>>> {k:d[k] for k in sorted(d,key=lambda x: -int(x))}
{'88': 1, '65': 1, '13': 1, '12': 1, '11': 4, '2': 2}
```

With older Python versions convert the dictionary to a list with `list(d.items())` and use similar sorting.

Answer (score 2):

`score = {'eng': 33, 'sci': 85, 'math': 60}`

You can do it like this...

`score_sorted = sorted(score.items(), key=lambda x:x[0])`

If you wanna sort it by val, then `score_sorted = sorted(score.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])`. You can add reverse=True to change order as well.

Comment: We'll want to call dict(score_sorted) so transform the tuples back into a dictionary. Also, @Pytan, I don't thing we need to pass a key if we're just sorting by the key, as I believe that is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Don't use `dict` as a variable name as it is already a built-in function.

`your_dict = {'11': 4, '0': 2, '65': 1, '88': 1, '12': 1, '13': 1}` is better.

You can use `sample_list = list(your_dict.items())` which convets the given dict into a list.

In the Python Dictionary, `items()` method is used to return the list with all dictionary keys with values.

Use `sample_list.sort()` to sort the list.

To reverse the list, use `reverse = True`

```
sample_list = list(your_dict.items())
sample_list.sort(reverse = True)
```

Then use `dict = dict(sample_list)` to convert it into a dictionary and print it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
myDict= {'11': 4, '0': 2, '65': 1, '88': 1, '12': 1, '13': 1}
sortDict = {}

for i in sorted(myDict.keys()) :  
     sortDict[i] = myDict[i]

print(sortDict)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict= {'11': 4, '0': 2, '65': 1, '88': 1, '12': 1, '13': 1}
```

You can try dictionary comprehension like this

```
sorted_dict={k:dict[k] for k in sorted(dict)}
print(sorted_dict)
```